# Pyspark streams proccess 1 record per trigger

Tags: pyspark, spark-streaming, databricks, databricks-community-edition

I am trying the Databricks Developer Foundation Capstone but I cant seem to pass the streaming Exercises.

I am supposed to read a stream of json data, transform it and append it back to a table.

I created the DataFrame like this:

`df = (spark.readStream.schema(DDLSchema).option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1).json(stream_path))`

I then transformed it with `orders_df = df.select(...)`

```
ordersQuery = (orders_df.writeStream
               .outputMode("append")
               .format("delta")
               .partitionBy('submitted_yyyy_mm')
               .queryName(orders_table)
               .trigger(processingTime="1 second")
               .option("checkpointLocation", orders_checkpoint_path)
               .table(orders_table))
```

The transformation and everything works fine but the check at the end keeps failing and it says:

> Expected the first 20 triggers to processes 1 record per trigger | Failed

I googled the issue but I cant find answers to this anywhere.

Comment: Could you be more clear on what your issue is? Maybe state the question/assignment description or describe what you're trying to achieve here

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the checkpoint path will solve the issue. Try running:

```
dbutils.fs.rm(orders_checkpoint_path, True)
```